# Unknown build configuration warning

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to run my Flutter app on Android, I receive the following warning:
`WARNING: Unknown build configuraiton productiondebug, will assume release`

The app runs fine, but I would like to fix this issue. I couldn't find any reference to `productiondebug` in app. The `production` is the name of my flavor and I have a folder with this name under `android/app/src`. I also have `demo` flavor. I receive this warning when I'm trying to run my app from VS Code using `demo` flavor:
`flutter run --flavor demo -t lib/main_demo.dart`